# Prove that $\tan(A)\tan(B)=\tan^2(C)$

Tags: trigonometry

> If 
>   $$\frac {\tan(A-B)}{\tan(A)} + \frac{\sin^2C}{\sin^2A}=1 $$
>   Prove that:
>    $$\tan(A)\tan(B)=\tan^2(C)$$

Please help with the solution...I can't proceed with a clear view to prove the following

Comment: what are the variables $A,B,C$?

Comment: Corresponding angles

Comment: angles in a triangle?

Comment: No not that just angles

Comment: See https://socratic.org/questions/if-tan-a-b-tana-sin-2c-sin-2a-1-prove-that-tana-tanb-tan-2-c

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac {\tan(A-B)}{\tan{A}} + \frac{\sin^2C}{\sin^2A}=1$$ gives
$$\tan(A-B)+\frac{\sin^2C}{\sin{A}\cos{A}}=\tan{A}$$ or
$$\frac{\sin^2C}{\sin{A}\cos{A}}=\frac{\sin{B}}{\cos{A}\cos(A-B)}$$ or
$$\frac{\cos(A-B)}{\sin{A}\sin{B}}=\frac{1}{\sin^2C}$$ or
$$\cot{A}\cot{B}+1=1+\cot^2C$$ or
$$\tan{A}\tan{B}=\tan^2C.$$

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying both sides in $tan^2{A}$ you get:
$$tan(A-B)tan(A)+\frac{sin^2C}{cos^2A}=tan^2A$$
by definition we have $tan(A-B)=\frac{tanA-tanB}{1+tanAtanB}$ so let $x=tanAtanB$ therefore:$$\frac{tan^2A-x}{1+x}=tan^2A-\frac{sin^2C}{cos^2A}$$$$=\frac{1}{cos^2A}-\frac{sin^2C}{cos^2A}-1$$$$=\frac{cos^2C}{cos^2A}-1$$
after multiplying:
$$sin^2A-xcos^2A=cos^2C-cos^2A+xcos^2C-xcos^2A$$
which leads to:
$$sin^2C=xcos^2C$$
or
$$x=tan^2C$$
$$\Large tanAtanB=tan^2C$$